# Should I use the same analytics property to website and app?

Tags: web-applications, google-analytics, mobile-application

I'm using the google analytics to web and app. The app and web are sharing the same data. Should I use a property for both?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended because some set of reports won't be available. You will have to create customize reports to get the missing dimensions and metrics.

I would recommend using the userID feature (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en) with a roll-up property (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6096167?hl=en) to aggregate both traffic.

But to do so, you will need Google Analytics Premium.  If this is not a option, prepare to spend a lots of time recreating reports using customize reports.